# What's the best way to implement DB Router in Django?

Tags: django, database

I have implemented [Automatic DB Routing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/) in Django and using AWS Aurora for Database with replication. I have found a minor replication lag with my database which hampering the flow. Issue occurs let's say when a read queryset is getting executed with 'slave' then while updating value using that queryset showing error something like 'read-only access for that table.' that means for update it should route to master db.

Here is my DB Settings for Multiple DB:

```
DATABASES = {
    'master': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'STORAGE_ENGINE': 'MyISAM / INNODB / ETC',
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER': 'master',
        'PASSWORD': 'master',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',

    },
    'slave': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'STORAGE_ENGINE': 'MyISAM / INNODB / ETC',
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER': 'name',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',

    },

    'slave2': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'STORAGE_ENGINE': 'MyISAM / INNODB / ETC',
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER': 'name',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',

    }

}


DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['path.to.AuthRouter']
```

Please provide me the best way to handle multiple db route automatically in django.

```
"""
DB Router core class which auto selects required database configuration
"""
class AuthRouter:

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Reads go to a replica.
        """
        print 'db_for_read'
        print model
        return 'slave'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Writes always go to master ie default.
        """
        print 'db_for_write'
        print model
        return 'master'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Relations between objects are allowed if both objects are
        in the default/replica pool.
        """
        db_list = ('master', 'slave')
        if obj1._state.db in db_list and obj2._state.db in db_list:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        All non-auth models end up in this pool.
        """
        return True
```

Comment: Please post your `router.py` file.

Comment: @user31415629 Added now.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the read operations and isolate the writing operations for master DB like:
AuthRouter should call master DB since that's the fresh information from users.

```
class AuthRouter:

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Reads go to a replica.
        """
        return 'master'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Writes always go to master ie default.
        """
        return 'master'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Relations between objects are allowed if both objects are
        in the default/replica pool.
        """
        db_list = ('master', 'slave')
        if obj1._state.db in db_list and obj2._state.db in db_list:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        All non-auth models end up in this pool.
        """
        return True
class PrimaryReplicaRouter(object):
    """
    A router to control all read/write database operations.
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Reads go to a randomly-chosen replica.
        """
        return select_rand_db()

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Writes always go to primary.
        """
        return 'master'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Relations between objects are allowed if both objects are
        in the primary/replica pool.
        """
        return True

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        All non-auth models end up in this pool.
        """
        return True


def select_rand_db():
    from numpy.random import choice
    """
    this function returns rand db or default if running tests
    :return:
    """

    return choice(['master', 'slave'], p=[0.5, 0.5])
```